# Multiple grids of different models in the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

How can i have more than one grid of different models in the same view.

I don't understand very well how the grid of kendo works.
The thing is when i have one grid of one model, the grid always show me something in the view. This is my grid when i use only one grid.

**In HTML:**

```
@model IEnumerable<CampeonatoFutbol.Models.PartidoClub>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ClubDesc).Title("EQUIPO").Width(220);
        columns.Bound(c => c.PrtidoCodigo).Title("PJ").Width(60);
        columns.Bound(c => c.GolesClub).Title("GC").Width(60);
        columns.Bound(c => c.PuntosClub).Title("PUNTOS").Width(150);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 300px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .PageSizes(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
    )
```

)

This grid doesn't have a read method action, but it's calling this method action of the controller:

```
public ActionResult Campeonato()
{
    return View(list); // i return a list that is showing in the grid
}
```

The issue is here when i tried to show another grid of a different model like this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CampeonatoFutbol.Models.Player>()
    .Name("gridGoleadores")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.NombreJugador).Title("JUGADOR").Width(220);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ClubDesc).Title("EQUIPO").Width(60);
        columns.Bound(c => c.GolesJugador).Title("GOLES").Width(60);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 300px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .PageSizes(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()        
        .Read(read => read.Action("GoleadoresCampeonato", "Campeonato"))
        .PageSize(20)
        )
    )
```

This grid has an method action that it's never called in the controller.
This is the controller that has a list that i want to return in this grid:

```
public ActionResult GoleadoresCampeonato()
{
    return View(anotherList);
}
```

I tried this way too but it doesn't work:

```
public ActionResult GoleadoresCampeonato([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(anotherList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Only the first grid is showing me something, and i want the other grid shows me something too.

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have To Create One View Model For it Check below code for that :

```js
 public partial class MasterModel
    {

//For single 
         public virtual Player Player{ get; set; }

         public virtual PartidoClub PartidoClub{ get; set; }

//For List    
         public List<PartidoClub> liPartidoClub { get; set; }

         public List<Player > liPlayer { get; set; }


    }


//Your Code On View 

@model Application.Model.MasterModel

//For First Grid On Same View 

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.liPartidoClub)
.Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ClubDesc).Title("EQUIPO").Width(220);
        columns.Bound(c => c.PrtidoCodigo).Title("PJ").Width(60);
        columns.Bound(c => c.GolesClub).Title("GC").Width(60);
        columns.Bound(c => c.PuntosClub).Title("PUNTOS").Width(150);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 300px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .PageSizes(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
    )
)

//For Second Grid On Same View

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model.liPlayer>()
    .Name("gridGoleadores")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.NombreJugador).Title("JUGADOR").Width(220);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ClubDesc).Title("EQUIPO").Width(60);
        columns.Bound(c => c.GolesJugador).Title("GOLES").Width(60);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 300px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .PageSizes(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()        
        .Read(read => read.Action("GoleadoresCampeonato", "Campeonato"))
        .PageSize(20)
        )
    )
```

Hope This Code Will Help You !!